# Why won't or statement work in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, variables, client-side-scripting

I was looking at the w3schools JavaScript tutorial and found something that made it crash. I was trying to replace the break statement with the same thing in the second statement of the for loop. This isn't really a problem, I just think there's something I'm not understanding.

This was the code they had:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>

<p>A loop with a <b>break</b> statement.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { break; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And it works perfectly fine. Then I changed it to this:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>

<p>A loop with a <b>break</b> statement.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 10 || i !== 3; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then, if I run it, the webpage crashes.
if I change the or(`||`) to an and(`&&`), then it works.
Why is this?

Comment: Think about it: it will execute the loop *if `i` is smaller than 10, or if it's not 3*. When `i` is greater than 10, then what is it? It's certainly not 3. So the condition is always true.

Comment: @deceze Yes, that's true. I just did not think very much about it, I was just wondering.

Comment: also, the one working perfectly: `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  if (i === 3) { break; } }` if you think of it, this would just be `for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i < 10 || i !== 3` will be always `true` since either `i < 10` OR `i >= 10` and thus `i !== 3`. So the loop will continue forever and hang the browser.

The second part of the `for` statement is a condition:

```
for (initialization; condition; afterthought)
```

It's evaluated in the begining of each cycle and if `true` the loop will go on with the next cycle.
Making it always `true` makes the loop running forever.